# Why LaTeX2e has this name?

Tags: latex-misc

LaTeX2e is, if I don't make any mistake, the successor of LaTeX 2.09, and was published in 1994 (I was 4 year old !). My question is very simple : why has called it LaTeX2e and not, for example LaTeX 2.10 ?

Comment: 3 was already taken and it seemed a big update for a .01 version increment

Comment: 3 was taken? http://latex-project.org/guides/ltx3info.pdf refers to 1995 as first reference.

Comment: That document dates from 1995, but I joined the project around the time of the 1992 DANTE meeting in Hamburg and there was already a working LaTeX3 format at that time. a year or two before we started working on 2e.

Comment: Whatever David say ...What do you expect?  Do not forget that the fauna inhabiting LaTeX is mainly people obsessed with mathematics and beautiful typography. The last 25 years the newer versions of TeX are always the Archimedes' constant pi. Thus, the occurrence of Addison-Wesley or someone (I do not kown) to include in the logo the beautiful greek letter epsilon with evident allusion to the Euler's number was a irresistible idea (I liked too).

Comment: I have forgotten mathematic, using LaTeX only for typography. I didn't think to Euler (I do not mathematic !)

Comment: @Fran no Metafont is converging on Euler's e: `This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818` in the way TeX is converging towards pi. The e in latex2e is representing an epsilon, the traditional notation for a small increment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ooopss, I've made a mess. Anyway, this is a additional evidence that greek letters with mathematical meaning are powerful totems.

Comment: as non mathematician and not physician user, I forget the meaning of ε for  "a small increment"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As Frank says [in his interview](http://tug.org/interviews/mittelbach.pdf)

> Although LaTeX2e already addressed most, if not all, of the
>   deficiencies identified in the first decade of LaTeX 2.09 use, it was
>   originally thought that LaTeX2e would only be an intermediate step
>   towards a LaTeX 3 version

So that really is the name 2-e or 2-epsilon, a small step towards 3.

Comment: Isn't the epsilon/e business something to do with Addison-Wesley?

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, or at least it was they who originally suggested that a .01 version increase wasn't a very good hook to advertise a major new system.