# How can I make this xparse command work inside environments?

Tags: environments, expl3, xparse

I have a `LaTeX3e` code for creating autokey exercise lists for my students. I need to create a list of exercises with the following structure (it's in Portuguese, but never mind the content):

[image]

As it's noticed, the questions are indented via enumerate environment, in which the numbers stay in a distinct "column", in some distance of the actual questions.

Thing is, the command for collecting answer keys, for some reason, doesn't work inside the enumerate environment.

Here's a MWE of my problem:

```
\documentclass[23pt, oneside]{book}


\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% first define the user interface
\NewDocumentCommand{\adddtolist}{O{general}m}
 {
  \marinho_lists_add:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\listoutputformat}{+m}
 {
  \marinho_lists_output_format:n { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\outputlist}{m}
 {
  \marinho_lists_output:n { #1 }
 }

% define the internal functions
\cs_new_protected:Nn \marinho_lists_add:nn
 {
  % create the sequence if it doesn't exist
  \seq_if_exist:cF { l_marinho_lists_#1_seq }
   {
    \seq_new:c { l_marinho_lists_#1_seq }
   }
  % add the item in the form {<number>}{<text>}
  \seq_put_right:cx { l_marinho_lists_#1_seq }
   {% compute the number based on the sequence length
    { \int_to_arabic:n { \seq_count:c { l_marinho_lists_#1_seq } + 1 } }
    { \exp_not:n { #2 } }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \marinho_lists_output_format:n
 {% the private function holds the format
  \cs_set:Nn \__marinho_lists_output_current:nn { #1 }
 }
\marinho_lists_output_format:n { #1~--~#2 \par } % a default

\cs_new_protected:Nn \marinho_lists_output:n
 {% map the sequence using the current format
  \seq_map_function:cN { l_marinho_lists_#1_seq } \__marinho_lists_item:n
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__marinho_lists_item:n
 {% \__marinho_lists_item:n receives an argument in the form {<number>}{<text>}
  % which we pass to \__marinho_lists_output_current:nn as two arguments
  \__marinho_lists_output_current:nn #1
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\key}[1]{\adddtolist[keylist]{#1}}
\newcommand{\showkey}{\outputlist{keylist}}

\usepackage{changepage}
\begin{document}

1. Here's my first question.
\key{As you see, it appears on the list by the end.}

2. Here's my second question.
\key{Again, it appears on the list os keys.}

\begin{enumerate}
\item However, if I try to put the command inside this environment
\key{It doesn't appear on the list.}
\end{enumerate}

\listoutputformat{\textbf{Question #1}: #2\par}
\showkey

\end{document}
```

One solution I tried was to indent the document text with the `changepage` package, using the `adjustwidth` environment, but it didn't work either.

Any thoughts on some solution, on how could I list my questions with the number as described?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First and most important, there is no LaTeX3ε (not in the foreseeable future, at least). LaTeX2ε was initially supposed to be a step from LaTeX 2.09 towards LaTeX3, thus this name (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228042/134574)), and LaTeX3 is not released as a format yet (it's [scheduled to 3019](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=49676921#49676921)). Since we're not planning LaTeX4 just yet, we don't have a LaTeX3ε ;-)

---

Jokes apart, your code didn't work because LaTeX environments form a TeX group, so non-global assignments are lost when the environments ends. Using `\seq_gput_right:cx` instead of `\seq_put_right:cx` (and renaming the `seq` variables to `g_...`) solves the problem:

> [image]

Other than that, nice code!

```latex
\documentclass[23pt, oneside]{book}


\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% first define the user interface
\NewDocumentCommand{\adddtolist}{O{general}m}
 {
  \marinho_lists_add:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\listoutputformat}{+m}
 {
  \marinho_lists_output_format:n { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\outputlist}{m}
 {
  \marinho_lists_output:n { #1 }
 }

% define the internal functions
\cs_new_protected:Nn \marinho_lists_add:nn
 {
  % create the sequence if it doesn't exist
  \seq_if_exist:cF { g_marinho_lists_#1_seq }
   {
    \seq_new:c { g_marinho_lists_#1_seq }
   }
  % add the item in the form {<number>}{<text>}
  \seq_gput_right:cx { g_marinho_lists_#1_seq }
   {% compute the number based on the sequence length
    { \int_to_arabic:n { \seq_count:c { g_marinho_lists_#1_seq } + 1 } }
    { \exp_not:n { #2 } }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \marinho_lists_output_format:n
 {% the private function holds the format
  \cs_set:Nn \__marinho_lists_output_current:nn { #1 }
 }
\marinho_lists_output_format:n { #1~--~#2 \par } % a default

\cs_new_protected:Nn \marinho_lists_output:n
 {% map the sequence using the current format
  \seq_map_function:cN { g_marinho_lists_#1_seq } \__marinho_lists_item:n
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__marinho_lists_item:n
 {% \__marinho_lists_item:n receives an argument in the form {<number>}{<text>}
  % which we pass to \__marinho_lists_output_current:nn as two arguments
  \__marinho_lists_output_current:nn #1
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\key}[1]{\adddtolist[keylist]{#1}}
\newcommand{\showkey}{\outputlist{keylist}}

\usepackage{changepage}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

1. Here's my first question.
\key{As you see, it appears on the list by the end.}

2. Here's my second question.
\key{Again, it appears on the list os keys.}

\begin{enumerate}
\item However, if I try to put the command inside this environment
\key{It doesn't appear on the list.}
\end{enumerate}

\listoutputformat{\textbf{Question #1}: #2\par}
\showkey

\end{document}
```

Comment: So sorry for the misconcept!!!

Comment: @ItaloMarinho No problem at all ;-)